# htop show different cpu usage with top

Tags: cpu-usage, top, htop

[image]

I'm running fedora in virtualbox with 2 cores. a.out is just a simple single-threaded program. I don't know why htop gives 200% CPU.

Comment: See https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/1204